# Add multiple fa files to a single AS3 class in Flash Professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, fireworks

I am making an animation in Flash professional and I need a constructor that can pick different movie clips that were converted from Fireworks. When I import the image in the Flash and convert it to a movie-clip and export to AS it requires a unique name. I want to have multiple images all into a single class is that possible?

When I go to edit the AS class it is basically empty

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class fallingSymbol extends MovieClip {


    public function fallingSymbol() {
        // constructor code
    }
}
```

}

I want to add to the class and put the extra movie clips in but I am not sure if that is even an option. My attempt is below  I created a blank class and cut and pasted the above in there. Doesn't seem to work.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class fallingSymbol {

    public function fallingSymbol() {
        // constructor code
    }


    public class Integral extends MovieClip {

        public function Integral() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

    public class Multiplication extends MovieClip {


    public function Multiplication() {
        // constructor code
    }
}

}
```

}
Any ideas?

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what you're asking here.  If what you desire is simply one bitmap image per MovieClip instance, without any added behavior, you may want to consider creating a loader (i.e. simply load the bitmap at runtime, instead of embedding it) or using the `[Embed]` metadata tag. Otherwise this seems to me like a question that should be asked in Adobe's own Flash support discussion forum, because it is not really related to programming at all, but rather a "how to" concerning a specific toolset.

Comment: Regarding `[Embed]`, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768780/embed-bitmap-in-actionscript3 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053546/howto-embed-images-in-actionscript-3-flex-3-the-right-way or http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html

Comment: thanks I get what you are saying